# Determing if a RewardedVideoAd is paused?

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

There are onVideoStart, onVideoOpen, and onVideoClosed-events.
Is there some way to get if the video is paused by the "Close video"-dialog?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like AdMob doesn't have triggers on this event **(on Video Paused)**. But if there isn't any **super specific case** I would stick with this callback `void onRewarded(RewardItem reward)` which is returned when a user gets through the ad and deserves the reward. Means he watched the whole video and you earned something.

Take a look here [googleads-mobile-android-examples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/java/admob/RewardedVideoExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/ads/rewardedvideoexample/MainActivity.java) and [Rewarded Video Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video). There it's perfectly explained. *Good luck*